# Make an Array from another array

Tags: php

I have an array.

my array:

```
while($rowop = mysql_fetch_array($resultop))
{
    $info[] = array(
        'status'=>$rowop[2],
        'day' => $rowop[3],
        'from'=>$rowop[4],
        'to' => $rowop[5],
        'mon'=>$rowop[6],
        'tue' => $rowop[7],
        'wed'=>$rowop[8],
        'thu' => $rowop[9],
        'fri'=>$rowop[10],
        'sat' => $rowop[11],
        'sun'=>$rowop[12]
    );
}
```

now if value of mon and fri is='on'. then i want to make another array that result will be same as:

```
status'=>ok,
'day' => all,
'from'=>12pm,
'to' => 8am,
'off day'=>tue,wed,thu,sat,sun
```

Any one please give me Idea

Comment: Just an if () {} else {} will work.

Comment: `if ($rowop[6] == 'on' && ...)`

Comment: ...and btw, mysql_ is depcrecated :)

Comment: can you give me any example @BriceFavre

Comment: `if ($rowop[6] == 'on' && rowop[10] == 'on') { // My second array }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($rowop[6] == 'on' && $rowop[10] == 'on') {
    $info[] = array(
        'status' => 'ok',
        'day' => 'all',
        'from' => '12pm',
        'to' => '8am',
        'off day' => 'tue,wed,thu,sat,sun'
    );
} else {
    $info[] = array(
        'status'=>$rowop[2],
        'day' => $rowop[3],
        'from'=>$rowop[4],
        'to' => $rowop[5],
        'mon'=>$rowop[6],
        'tue' => $rowop[7],
        'wed'=>$rowop[8],
        'thu' => $rowop[9],
        'fri'=>$rowop[10],
        'sat' => $rowop[11],
        'sun'=>$rowop[12]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($info['mon'] == 'on' && $info['fri'] == 'on'){
    $array = array(
        'status'=>'ok',
        'day'=>'all',
        'from'=>'12pm',
        'to'=>'8am',
        'off_day'=>'tue,wed,thu,sat,sun'
    );
}
```

Note: Array key's value must always be inside "" when it's not an int(number).